# cURL - SSL Handshake consumes more time than starttransfert

Tags: ssl, curl, timing

I did make an request to a server with:

```bash
curl -w "\n\n \
DNS: %{time_namelookup}\n \
Connect: %{time_connect}\n \
SSL: %{time_appconnect}\n \
Pretransfer: %{time_pretransfer}\n \
TTFB: %{time_starttransfer}\n\n \
Total: %{time_total}\n\n "\
-o /dev/null -k -s "https://testserver.local"`
```

And my output was this:

```
DNS: 0.006105
Connect: 0.207161
SSL: 0.487719
Pretransfer: 0.280635
TTFB:    0.577115
Total:   0.585572
```

Look at SSL and Pretransfer. How does this happen?

According to [cloudflares curl timing post](https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-question-of-timing/) pretransfer should happen after ssl, in my test case ssl takes a lot longer than pretransfer.